# Sum of absolute values is finite

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, summation

Suppose $\lambda_m \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $\sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert i + \lambda_m \rvert^{-p} < \infty$. Then why does
$$\sum_{(m,n) \in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}} \left\lvert i \pm \sqrt{\lambda_m^2 + n^2} \right\rvert^{-(p+1+\varepsilon)} < \infty$$
hold?

Comment: I edited the question to fix the error.

Comment: What is $\varepsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following calculation:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}} \left\lvert i \pm \sqrt{\lambda_m^2 + n^2} \right\rvert^{-(p+1+\varepsilon)} & = \sum_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}} \left\lvert i \pm \sqrt{\lambda_m^2 + n^2} \right\rvert^{-p}\left\lvert i \pm \sqrt{\lambda_m^2 + n^2} \right\rvert^{-(1+\varepsilon)} \\
& \leq \sum_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}} \left\lvert i +\lambda_m \right\rvert^{-p}\left\lvert i +n \right\rvert^{-(1+\varepsilon)} \\
& \leq \sum_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}} \left\lvert i +\lambda_m \right\rvert^{-p}\left\lvert n \right\rvert^{-(1+\varepsilon)} \\
& \leq \sum_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}} \left\lvert i +\lambda_m \right\rvert^{-p} \sum_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}} n^{-(1+\varepsilon)} \\
& < \infty
\end{align*}
This should do the job